# Generating OpenVPN static keys in memory?

Tags: openvpn, openssl

I know I can generate an OpenVPN static key by 'openvpn --genkey --secret myfile.key'.
In python, I am currently using a shell call to generate a key, open the 'myfile.key' and read it back in.  It would be much cleaner if I could do it without the shell call.

Does anyone know what type of key is generated with the --genkey command, or a way to generate the key directly in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenVPN doesn't currently provide Python APIs.  However, one way to (slightly) clean up your script would be to have it generate the key directly to `stdout`, and then use the `stdout` returned by `Popen`.

```
openvpn --genkey --secret /dev/stdout
```

I.e.,

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen("openvpn --genkey --secret /dev/stdout", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
```

As far as I know, even though the keys are generated using the TLS PRF function, there's no "other" way to generate the keys.

Comment: *facepalm*  Why didn't I think of writing to /dev/stdout?  Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem; happy to help!